# Как файловая система ext4 распределяет данные?

Tags: raid, ext4

Всем привет!

Есть `RAID0` из двух дисков по `450 Gb` и того общий объём свободного пространства для файловой системы `~900 Gb`. И есть данные, `400 gb` которые размещаем на RAID0 потому что хотим обращаться пользуясь его преимуществами. То есть получить iops = (iops одного диска) x 2.

Но вопрос, как эти данные распределяться физически на дисках? 
Если 400 Gb будут физически находиться на одном из дисков RAID0, то мы не увидим особого прироста производительности, больше того, чем был бы будь эти данные просто на одном диске, без RAID всякого.

Или умная файловая система ext4 размажет эти 400 Гб равномерно между двумя 450+450 дискам (свободному пространству 900 Гб) и тогда можно ожидать прироста в чтении/записи даже будь у нас 100 Гб на 900 Гб свободном пространстве.

Comment: Я думаю что практически все файловые системы располагают данные более менее линейно (кластер за кластером и т п). Вопрос как raid перераспределяет пространство. Врядли файловая система подстраивается под raid, она знать не знает что это.

Comment: Файловая система ничего не знает о том на чем она лежит. Нулевой же рейд кладет кластеры ровно через один четные на один диск не четные на другой. так что добится неравномерного распределения данных между дисками очень затруднительно

Comment: Mike, есть ссылка подтверждающая такую работу RAID0?

Answer (score 0):

Надо понимать, что ext4 ничего не знает о том, что она на самом деле на нескольких дисках. Она знает, что размещена на блочном устройстве размером 900 Гб, а кроме этого ей мало что известно. А RAID0 размазывает это блочное устройство, чередуя блоки между дисками.

Но скорее всего да, примерно равномерно. Связано это с тем, что ext4 сохраняет данные файлов в так называемых **экстентах**, которые представляют собой последовательные участки диска. Разница в распределении, за счёт RAID0, может чисто теоретически быть не более чем в один блок. Поэтому разница в долях места с разных дисков для всех экстентов, кроме совсем маленьких, крайне мала. Более того, если "атомом" для размера экстентов является не один блок, а что-то чётное, то данные будут точно размазаны равномерно.

Очень может быть, что создатели ext4 задумывались об этом.

Comment: Когда читал про Raid 0 не видел того что Raid 0 чередует блоки между дисками. Вы откуда про это узнали? В принципе логично конечно но хотелось бы подтверждений.